# iOS11 Swift4 CoreData: new data can be displayed but not add into database

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

This is my code to fetch the data and reload the tableView. The problem now is new data can be displayed, but not insert into database. The block quotes is output of my Xcode.

coreData : Optional("huang") is the new data.

> CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZINCONSISTENCIES, t0.ZMISSINGHIPERS, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPES, t0.ZSCORE, t0.ZUPDATEDTIME FROM ZREPORT t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNAME
>
> CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0008s
>
> CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0010s for 2 rows.
>
> coreData : Optional("huang")
>
> coreData : Optional("test1")
>
> coreData : Optional("test2")

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("pwd: \(NSHomeDirectory())")

    let addMoreButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named:"navbar_icon_create_default"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(createNewReport))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addMoreButton

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Report")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as?
        AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            reports = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Report]
            reports.forEach{ entity in
                print("coreData : \(entity.name)")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding a new data to the coredata. This is my testing code

```
var reports:[Report] = []
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
let report = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Report", in: context!)
let reportDetail = NSManagedObject(entity: report!, insertInto: context) as! Report
reportDetail.inconsistencies = 3
reportDetail.pes = 4
reportDetail.missingHIPERs = 6
reportDetail.name = "huang"
reportDetail.updatedTime = nil
reportDetail.score = "60"
print("pppp: \(reportDetail.missingHIPERs)")
reports.append(reportDetail)
self.cacheManager.store(reports: reports)
```

This is my store function code

```
func store(reports: [Report]) {
    let context = getContext()

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Report", in:  context)

    reports.forEach { report in
        let reportDetail = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Report
        reportDetail.name = report.name
        reportDetail.inconsistencies = report.inconsistencies
        reportDetail.missingHIPERs = report.missingHIPERs
        reportDetail.score = report.score
        reportDetail.pes = report.pes
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved")
    }catch{
        print("Could not save the report detail as: \(error)")
    }
}
```

And as the two pictures show below, the process to save the data seems to work(The print function work). And my App can refresh the tableView after the adding data.
The two other datas are manually added by myself using sqlite tools, they can always display. But the new data never add into the database. I opened the sqlite outputting in console.

[image: Xcode Output]

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

So, what's the problem?

1. I thinking maybe the data detail I add is not correct, because as the Xcode showing, all data is in '?' form.

Comment: Those `?` should be correct. These are [parameters](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) used in [prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).